# Cannot load windows 10 in dual boot with ubuntu 16.10

Tags: dual-boot

Need Help!

I installed ubuntu 16.10 on my windows 10 laptop in second partition of the hard drive now I cannot load windows from the grub as the error says 'cannot load image'... Ubuntu is loading fine.
I assume that I did not select the root folder while installing ubuntu by mistake if this is the case..
Is there any ways to solve this without reinstalling ubuntu?

Comment: Did you install in UEFI mode, is windows installed in UEFI mode? You can try booting a live Ubuntu disk, mounting and chrooting into your system, and installing grub with grub-install. Specifics: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: Have you manually create partition ?

Comment: Had to uninstall ubuntu after lot of frustrations, now windows is also not loading. The screen shows grub> .... can't proceed to load windows. any suggesstion please?